# What are the purposes of AuthenticationManager.SignIn vs AuthenticationManager.AuthenticateAsync?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin

`AuthenticationManager` has two methods.

```
void SignIn(params ClaimsIdentity[] identities);
Task<AuthenticateResult> AuthenticateAsync(string authenticationType);
```

What are their purposes? In what situations should they each be used?

Comment: Did you try this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.iauthenticationmanager.authenticateasync(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: I would like this question to have a really good answer including an explanation that helps a lot of people. That's why I have added the bounty. I don't want a link. (but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the purposes are described on the names of the methods **Authenticate** and **SignIn**

So the purpose of **AuthenticateAsync** is basically get an *Authentication Ticket*

```
await ticket 
 = Authentication.AuthenticateAsync(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer);
```

it returns an *AuthenticateResult* like this

```
{Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticateResult}
    Description: {Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationDescription}
    Identity: {System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity}
    Properties: {Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationProperties}
```

and with this *Result* you can now **SignIn** (Add the Identity information to the context)

```
Context.Authentication.SignIn(ticket.Properties, ticket.Identity);
```

You can see it very clearly in the sample code below

```
var ticket = await Context.Authentication.AuthenticateAsync(Options.AuthenticationType);

    if(ticket != null)
    {
      Context.Authentication.SignIn(ticket.Properties, ticket.Identity);

      Response.Redirect(ticket.Properties.RedirectUri);

      return true;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is the description of these two methods based on visual studio tool-tip.
It may be useful.

[image: AuthenticationManager.SignIn]
[image: AuthenticationManager.AuthenticateAsync]

Comment: For a bounty of a 100 points, this is a pretty light on details answer. I can look at the tool tip myself.